Are there tense short vowels in English that are mistakenly included under "schwa" or /ɪ/ by dictionaries?
for example, the second vowel in "savage"?
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/savage_1?q=savage

savage adjective


/ˈsævɪdʒ/


/ˈsævɪdʒ/


aggressive and violent; causing great harm


Why "mistakenly"?

It is clearly not a schwa and it is a big strech to call it an instance of /I/.  Phonetically, it is a short version of  monophthongal /eɪ/ for which no symbol seems to exist in English phonology @Draconis

In which dialect? For me (Midwestern American) "savage" rhymes with "midge", except a bit more centralized because it's unstressed.

it's also not at all clear what you mean by "a short version of monophthongal /eɪ/"

"monophthongal [o]" was said to be in Sara Palin's speech when she descended on the public scene.  Linguists transcribe long a as a diphthong eɪ but now imagine it without the  ɪ element and shortened.  Thats how I hear second a in the AmE "savage" at the OALD. @draconis

ok, so [e] then?

@SK I don’t know which dialect you’re describing, but the vowel in the second syllable of savage quite clearly is a schwa for many speakers, and it equally clearly is [ɪ] for many others. There may be speakers who pronounce it more like [e], perhaps in various forms of Indian or African English(?), but they certainly do not constitute a majority of native speakers.

Some dialects of English have two different reduced vowels: a higher one, as in "edition", and a lower one, as in "addition". (In other dialects, they have merged, and those words are homophones.)
Sources differ on how to transcribe this difference—unfortunately, Wells doesn't have separate lexical sets for them. The lower one is pretty much universally transcribed as /ə/. For the higher one, options include /ɪ/, /ɨ/, and /ᵻ/. I've never seen it transcribed as /e/, but given how similar [e] is to [ɪ], I wouldn't be surprised if some dialect pronounced it that way.
Combining the two is often called the Rosa's~roses merger, but that's not actually a great example of it. I pronounce those two words distinctly, because of the clitic boundary in "Rosa's", but pronounce "edition" and "addition" identically.

I've never heard anyone call the weak vowel merger the Rosa's-roses merger. AFAIK it's just a famous pair that illustrates the higher quality of morpheme-internal /ə/.

interestingly, I definitely have unmerged Rosa's and roses, but I think my addition and edition are merged. Not sure how unusual that is, or what exactly the conditioning there is (or if it's just lexically diffused)

@Tristan That's the case with most North American English speakers. The weak vowels /ɪ/ and /ə/ are merged, but it has a lower quality in a morpheme-final position like Rosa.

@Nardog that doesn't seem related to my comment. I generally lack the merger, but do have addition and edition merged, which is unrelated to the specific quality of the merged vowel in merging dialects

@Tristan I'm saying most North American English speakers do not merge Rosa's and roses but do merge addition and edition. The weak vowel merger doesn't affect the former pair because of the difference in morphology (/'roʊzə#z/ vs /'roʊz#əz/).

Ah, thanks for the clarification. That;'s interesting as I'm British (and speak fairly Standard Southern British English, albeit with a few more traditional RP elements). I'm pretty sure I don't merge Lennon & Lenin, or rhyme abbot and rabbit though, so whatever conditioning is going on for me must be different
